# Map Reducing (Key, Value) tuples where Value is a dictionary in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, mapreduce

New to the spark way of thinking. My mapper returns (key, dict) tuples of the form:

```
[('abc', {'min': 2}), ('def', {'min': 3})]
[('abc', {'min': 4}), ('def', {'min': 5})]
[('geh', {'nullable': 1}))]
```

And need to reduce to:

```
[('abc', {'min': 6}), ('def', {'min': 8}), ('geh', {'nullable': 1)]
```

My reducer below just returns one of the partitions instead of aggregating by the key and incrementing the nested value.

```
errors_distribution = dataFrame.rdd \
    .mapPartitions(error_schema_wrapper(validation_schema)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a,b:{**a,**b}) \
    .collectAsMap()
```

Does anyone know how to reduce a nested dictionary like this? Using Python 3.7.11

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following will work:

```
d = [('abc', {'min': 2}), ('def', {'min': 3}),
    ('abc', {'min': 4}), ('def', {'min': 5}),
    ('geh', {'nullable': 1})]
d_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(d)
d_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda d1, d2: {key : d1[key] + d2[key] for key in d1.keys()}).collectAsMap()
```

output:

```
{'geh': {'nullable': 1}, 'def': {'min': 8}, 'abc': {'min': 6}}
```

Each (key, dict) pair is merged by returning a new dictionary where the values of each dictionary key has been added. This only works if the dictionaries being merged contain the same keys.